# print image as a background-image

Tags: theming, media

The page.tpl.php prints the header image like so. I need to change it so that it prints it as a background image. i.e `<div style="background-image:"' . $url . '"></div>`  When I make that change the value of $url changes and includes additional text, not just the path to the image as it does in this format. How can I change this?

```
if ($node->field_header_image && $node->field_header_image['und'][0]['uri']) {
        $url = file_create_url($node->field_header_image['und'][0]['uri']);
        echo '<img src="' . $url . '" width="100%">';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving the absolute url of the file correctly, but your quotes in style attribute are a little mixed up.

Try this:

```
<?php 
print '<div style="background-image:url(' . $url . ');"></div>';
?>
```